# How to solve for when this trigonometric function intersects the line $y=1$?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

How can I solve for $\alpha$ in
$$4\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^{3}\left(t-r\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=1$$
on the domain $0\leq\alpha\leq\pi$? Clearly, one solution is when $\alpha=\pi$, but through plotting, it seems to only hold true when $t-r$ is less than a value around $0.3$. When $t-r$ is greater than this value,  it seems to have different solutions.

```
NSolve[HoldForm[4*Sin[\[Alpha]/2]*Cos*(\[Alpha]/2)^3*(t - r) + Sin[\[Alpha]/2]] == 1 && 0 <= \[Alpha] <= Pi, \[Alpha], Reals]
```

I am very new so I don't have much code.

Comment: just want to make sure, is this a question about how to solve this problem in the software program *Mathematica*, or should this question be migrated to the Mathematics stackexchange instead? If it's about mathematica, please post your code so people don't have to type it out again! :)

Comment: Please include in your question the code that you have tried and what you obtained.

Comment: @thorimur I am trying to solve it in Mathematica but I am new so I don't have the tools to solve it. I don't think it's possible to solve it algebraically, which is why I didn't think of posting it on Math stack exchange, but I know there are other solutions. I don't really have much code, but I guess I can post the equation in Mathematica format.

Comment: You have syntax errors. Eliminate HoldForm, and use `Cos[\[Alpha]/2]^3` instead of `Cos*(\[Alpha]/2)^3`. Then, use `N @ Solve[..]` instead of `NSolve`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sol = Solve[
     4*Sin[a/2]*Cos[a/2]^3*tr + Sin[a/2] == 1 && 0 <= a <= Pi, {a, tr}, 
      Reals]

(*   {{a -> \[Pi]}, {tr -> 
       ConditionalExpression[1/4 Csc[a/2] Sec[a/2]^3 (1 - Sin[a/2]), 
        0 < a < \[Pi]]}}   *)

Plot[Evaluate[tr /. sol], {a, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic]

{min = Minimize[tr /. sol[[2]], a], min // N}

(*   {{-(1/4) Csc[
2 ArcTan[Root[1 + 2 #1 - 10 #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 3]]] Sec[
2 ArcTan[Root[1 + 2 #1 - 10 #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 3]]]^3 (-1 + 
 Sin[2 ArcTan[
    Root[1 + 2 #1 - 10 #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 3]]]), {a -> 
4 ArcTan[
  Root[1 + 2 #1 - 10 #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 
   3]]}}, {0.287482, {a -> 1.75015}}}   *)
```

Two solutions: 1. for a==Pi, any tr you like  2. For 0 < a < Pi, tr depending on a as shown in the graph.